# Image not loading in HTML when appended by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webpack

Image loads correctly in HTML, but not when appended through jQuery.

The project is set up through webpack and images are loaded through file-loader. The code works correctly when directly typed into HTML however, it doesnt work when I attempt to load it through jQuery.

For HTML :

```
<img src = {require('../images/icon1.png')} className = 'studentIcon' />
```

For jQuery :

```
$("#students").append(
  $("<div class = 'row'>").append(
    $("<div class = 'col-xs-4'>").append(
      "<img src = {require('../images/icon1.png')} />"
    )
  )
)
```

In HTML the jQuery appended images shows up as:

```
<img src="{require('../images/icon1.png')}">
```

with Console error:

> icon1.png')%7D:1 GET http://localhost:8080/%7Brequire('../images/icon1.png')%7D 404 (Not Found)

When directly inserted into HTML the images shows correctly, however I have a large number of images which I want to directly attach to some generated code.

Comment: You only need `../images/icon1.png` not `{require('../images/icon1.png')}`

Comment: Your template-engine is parsing the html-code, but not the jquery. So the jquery-appended code will not be parsed by your template-engine.

Comment: Nested `.append()` does not look good to me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "nest" many `.append()` methods like this.
But what you definitely have to do is to concatenate the string (`+` sign) with your templating (which runs first), else it's just characters that are part of the string as is.

Here is what you want:

```
$("#students").append("<div class = 'col-xs-4'><img src = "+{require('../images/icon1.png')}+" /></div>");
```

And a more "visual/readable" way for the same:

```
$("#students")
  .append("<div class = 'col-xs-4'>"+
            "<img src = "+{require('../images/icon1.png')}+" />"+
          "</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Would advise the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var students = $("#students");
  var row = $("<div>", {
    class: "row"
  }).appendTo(students);
  var col = $("<div>", {
    class: "col-xs-4"
  }).appendTo(row);
  $("<img>", {
    src: "../images/icon1.png"
  }).appendTo(col);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="students">
</div>
```

This jQuery creates the various HTML Elements as jQuery OIbjects, appends them as needed, and adds them to the DOM. For the Image Source, it is a relative path to the location on the web server.

Hope that helps.